# How to convert Unicode string to Cyrillic format

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have this kind of string "%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_67haV9G.jpg" . I need to convert it to "Безымянный_67haV9G.jpg" . Could you please help me with that?

Comment: That's not an Unicode string. Well, it is but every string is one. This is just URI encoded, so just decode it.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use below to convert Unicode string to Cyrillic:**

```
decodeURIComponent("YourstringToCyrillic")
```